# Alexander polynomial of some 2-component links

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

I would like to understand whether the multivariate Alexander polynomial of a link $L$ does not vanish everywhere for a certain class of links; I don't know the links' diagrams in general but I have some information:

- $L$ has two components, say $K_1$ and $K_2$;
- each component is unknotted (considered singularly), and in particular $K_1$ is a simple curve;
- $K_2$ is contained in the solid torus which is the complement of $K_1$;
- the linking number of the components vanishes, i.e. $lk(K_1, K_2)=0$. So, $K_2$ is homotopically trivial in the exterior of $K_1$;
- $L$ is non-split.

An example of such a link is the Whitehead link $W$, whose Alexander polynomial is $\Delta_W(t_1, t_2)=(1-t_1)(1-t_2)$.[image: The Whitehead link]

The only general result I was able to find in the literature is that the Alexander polynomial $\Delta_L(t_1, t_2)$ evaluted in $(t_1, 1)$ is equal to zero, i.e. $\Delta_L(t_1, 1)=0$, unfortunately. My guess, just for the records, is that the Alexander polynomials of such links does not vanish everywhere. Any ideas or references are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there are such examples where the Alexander polynomial is zero. Consider the link [L11n244](http://katlas.org/wiki/L11n244), pictured below.

[image]

Both the [Knot Atlas](http://katlas.org/wiki/Main_Page) and [Link Info](https://linkinfo.sitehost.iu.edu/) have it listed as having multivariable Alexander polynomial of zero. The picture above satisfies all of your conditions except that neither component is "simple" (which I'm taking to mean a diagram of the unknot with no crossings). But one can just isotope the diagram so that either of the components are simple. I've done that for the blue component below.

[image]

It occurs to me that maybe you meant something else with your third condition: $K_2$ is contained in the solid torus which is the complement of $K_1$. The reason I say that is if $K_1$ is an unknot, then its complement is a solid torus. So any two component link $L=K_1\cup K_2$ where $K_1$ is trivial would have $K_2$ contained in the solid torus complement of $K_1$.

Comment: Perfect answer, this link is a counterexample to what I hoped was true! Thank you very much:D